# reading in tab delimited text file with tidyverse readr - columns not parsing

Tags: r, readr

I am trying to read in a tab delimited text file that consists of a header or column names and decimal number data in the rows that follow. readr is however not parsing the data correctly - it sees the entire header as one long set of characters instead of columns so I end up with single column data - and I am not sure how to resolve this. Below is what the it looks like when I read in the data:

```
data <- read_tsv("data.txt")
```

> Rows: 62893 Columns: 1
> ── Column specification ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
> Delimiter: "\t"
> chr (1): Lon Lat Col1 Col2 Col3...

> ℹ Use `spec()` to retrieve the full column specification for this data.

> ℹ Specify the column types or set `show_col_types = FALSE` to quiet this message.

When I print out the first few lines this what I get:

```
head(data)
```

> # A tibble: 3 × 1

> Lon Lat Col1 Col2 Col3

> *<chr>*

> 1 "-123.25 38.25 0.000002 0.030371 0.000002"

> 2 "96.25 67.75 0.308539 0.063202 0.000019"

> 3 "-73.75 -15.75 0.018868 0.048092 0.013427"

> # ℹ abbreviated name:

> # ` Lon Lat Col1 Col2 Col3 `

Any ideas on how to get readr to pars this table correctly so so it sees the data as 3 rows and 5 columns instead of 3 rows and 1 column? And recognizes that the first row is a header column? (I tried using the col_names = TRUE attribute of the read_tsv() function and that did not work). It clearly sees each row a single long character string, including the first (header) row but shouldn't because the data is tab delimited.

Comment: I think base on your data, the separator (delimiter) should be space not tab (" ").
read.csv("data.txt", sep=" ") works for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just copy and paste the data from above:

data.txt

```
Lon Lat Col1 Col2 Col3
-123.25 38.25 0.000002 0.030371 0.000002
96.25 67.75 0.308539 0.063202 0.000019
-73.75 -15.75 0.018868 0.048092 0.013427
```

you can use `read.csv` and specify the `sep` parameter as space `" "`:

```
read.csv("data/data.txt", sep=" ")
#      Lon    Lat     Col1     Col2     Col3
#1 -123.25  38.25 0.000002 0.030371 0.000002
#2   96.25  67.75 0.308539 0.063202 0.000019
#3  -73.75 -15.75 0.018868 0.048092 0.013427
```